# using Grub to boot windows 7 off an extended partition

Tags: windows-7, grub

I am trying to set up a multi-boot computer with grub that will allow the user to boot to VxWorks or one of several windows instances.

The partitions are set up like the following:

Vxworks - (hd0,0) and (hd0,1)
Windows1 - (hd0, 3)
then an extended partition with two windows partitions inside it:
(hd0, 4) and (hd0,5)

With XP what I did to solve this was put this in the menu.lst:

> title ExtendedXP
>   hide (hd0,0)
>   hide (hd0,1)
>   hide (hd0,3)
>   hide (hd0,4)
>   rootnoverify (hd0,3)
>   makeactive
>   rootnoverify (hd0,5)
>   chainloader +1
>   savedefault

and then modify the boot.ini file in the extended partition to correctly identify itself as the windows target.  This would use the ntloader on the primary Windows partition then look at the boot.ini file on the extended windows partition and boot to that target.

However, I am not sure how to do this with win7 as bootmgr is a bit different than NT loader.  Is there a way to accomplish the same thing?